# Linking error trying to make module with boost python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I'm trying to create example boost.python module, but i have only link errors

The boost was built with command

```
b2 --with-python address-model=64 toolset=msvc --build-dir=build link=shared install stage
```

the cmake file is this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(my_project)

find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)

message("found python, version = ${Python_VERSION}")
message("found python, version_major = ${Python_VERSION_MAJOR}")
message("found python, version_minor = ${Python_VERSION_MINOR}")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python)

message("Boost Dir: ${Boost_DIR}")
message("Boost Found: ${Boost_FOUND}")
message("Boost Found: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_library(my_module MODULE my_module.cpp wrap.cpp)

message("trying to link with ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")


target_include_directories(my_module PRIVATE ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_module PRIVATE ${Python_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(my_module PRIVATE Boost::python)
```

the output: wrap.obj : error LNK2019: reference to deprecated extern symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl boost::python::thr
ow_error_already_set(void)" (_*imp*?throw_error_already_set@python@boost@@YAXXZ) в функции "struct _object * __cdecl bo
ost::python::expect_non_null(struct _object *)" (??$expect_non_null@U_object@@@python@boost@@YAPEAU_obj
ect@@PEAU2@@Z). [...\build\my_module.vcxproj] ans so on ...

wrap.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "my_module.h"

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( example )
{
    class_<Some>( "Some" )
        .def( init<int,string>( args( "some_id", "name" ) ) )
        .def( "ID", &Some::ID )
        .def( "Name", &Some::Name, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>() )
        .def( "ResetID", static_cast< void (Some::*)() >( &Some::ResetID ) )
        .def( "ResetID", static_cast< void (Some::*)(int) >( &Some::ResetID ), args( "some_id" ) )
        .def( "ChangeName", &Some::ChangeName, args( "name" ) )
        .def( "SomeChanges", &Some::SomeChanges, args( "some_id", "name" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, is that you are linking to Boost::python, while the exact python version is 3.10. Therefor, you should link to Boost::python310 and find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python310) or any another version of python (I know, that your  python version is 310, because I'am you)